# Android HorizontalScrollView holds touch event even when it cannot scroll any more

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview, intercept

I have a ViewPager with 3 pages, the last page is HorizontalScrollView.
The problem is that when I scroll left in HorizontalScrollView page, page won't change even when scroll position is 0.

[image: If I scroll from page2 to page1 page scrolls normally]
If I scroll from page2 to page1 page scrolls normally.
[image: If I scroll from page3 to page2 ScrollView prevents page from scrolling]
If I scroll from page3 to page2 ScrollView prevents page from scrolling.

To return to previous page in HorizontalScrollView, I have to fling left.
I tried disabling intercepting of HorizontalScrollView when position is 0 and scroll X-velocity is minus, but it didn't work.
I want to pass TouchEvent to ViewPager IMMEDIATELY if I scroll left when scroll position is 0, so that ViewPager can change page to previous.

What should I do?

**Source Code Added:**

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pagerscrollviewtest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

page1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="PAGE 1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

page2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.pagerscrollviewtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.setCount(3);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    }
}
```

CustomPagerAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.pagerscrollviewtest;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private int mCount;

    private TextViewFragment mFragment0, mFragment1;
    private ScrollViewFragment mFragment2;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        mCount = 0;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) { mCount = count;}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if(mFragment0 != null)
                    return mFragment0;
                return TextViewFragment.newInstance("Page1");
            case 1:
                if(mFragment1 != null)
                    return mFragment1;
                return TextViewFragment.newInstance("Page2");
            case 2:
                if(mFragment2 != null)
                    return mFragment2;
                return ScrollViewFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mFragment0 = (TextViewFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                mFragment1 = (TextViewFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 2:
                mFragment2 = (ScrollViewFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
        }
        return createdFragment;
    }
}
```

Page1View.java:

```
package com.example.pagerscrollviewtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Page1View extends LinearLayout
{
    private TextView mTitle;

    public Page1View(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Page1View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Page1View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.page1, this, true);


        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

    public void setTitle(String str)
    {
        mTitle.setText(str);
    }

}
```

Page2View.java:

```
package com.example.pagerscrollviewtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Page2View extends LinearLayout
{
    private HorizontalScrollView mScrollView;
    private LinearLayout mScrollItemContainer;

    public Page2View(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Page2View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Page2View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.page2, this, true);

        mScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        mScrollItemContainer = (LinearLayout) mScrollView.getChildAt(0);

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            TextView dummy = new TextView(getContext());
            dummy.setText("Text "+Integer.toString(i));
            mScrollItemContainer.addView(dummy);
        }
    }
}
```

TextViewFragment.java:

```
package com.example.pagerscrollviewtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TextViewFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static TextViewFragment newInstance(String title)
    {
        TextViewFragment instance = new TextViewFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        instance.setArguments(args);
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        Page1View view = new Page1View(getActivity());
        view.setTitle(args.getString("title"));
        return view;
    }
}
```

ScrollViewFragment.java:

```
package com.example.pagerscrollviewtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ScrollViewFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static ScrollViewFragment newInstance()
    {
        ScrollViewFragment instance = new ScrollViewFragment();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Page2View view = new Page2View(getActivity());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your complete code pls

Comment: @SilvansSolanki I added images and source code.